# Why xgboost can not deal with this simple sentence case?

Tags: machine-learning, python, random-forest, decision-trees, xgboost

There is only 1 feature dim. But the result is unreasonable. The code and data is below. The purpose of the code is to judge whether the two sentences are the same.

**In fact, the final input to the model is: feature is [1] with label 1, and feature is [0] with label 0.**

The data is quite simple:

---

sent1 sent2 label

我想听 我想听 1

我想听 我想说 0

我想说 我想说 1

我想说 我想听 0

我想听 我想听 1

我想听 我想说 0

我想说 我想说 1

我想说 我想听 0

我想听 我想听 1

我想听 我想说 0

我想说 我想说 1

我想说 我想听 0

我想听 我想听 1

我想听 我想说 0

我想说 我想说 1

我想说 我想听 0

我想听 我想听 1

我想听 我想说 0

我想说 我想说 1

我想说 我想听 0

---

```
import pandas as pd
import xgboost as xgb
d = pd.read_csv("data_small.tsv",sep=" ")


def my_test(sent1,sent2):
    result = [0]
    if "我想说" in sent1 and "我想说" in sent2:
        result[0] = 1
    if "我想听" in sent1 and "我想听" in sent2:
        result[0] = 1
    return result

fea_ = d.apply(lambda row: my_test(row['sent1'], row['sent2']), axis=1).tolist()

labels = d["label"].tolist()
fea = pd.DataFrame(fea_)
for i in range(len(fea_)):
    print(fea_[i],labels[i])

labels = pd.DataFrame(labels)
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# train_x_pd_split, valid_x_pd, train_y_pd_split, valid_y_pd = train_test_split(fea, labels, test_size=0.2,
#                                                                                random_state=1234)

train_x_pd_split = fea[0:16]
valid_x_pd = fea[16:20]
train_y_pd_split = labels[0:16]
valid_y_pd = labels[16:20]


train_xgb_split = xgb.DMatrix(train_x_pd_split, label=train_y_pd_split)
valid_xgb = xgb.DMatrix(valid_x_pd, label=valid_y_pd)
watch_list = [(train_xgb_split, 'train'), (valid_xgb, 'valid')]


params3 = {
    'seed': 1337,
    'colsample_bytree': 0.48,
    'silent': 1,
    'subsample': 1,
    'eta': 0.05,
    'objective': 'binary:logistic',
    'eval_metric': 'logloss',
    'max_depth': 8,
    'min_child_weight': 20,
    'nthread': 8,
    'tree_method': 'hist',
}

xgb_trained_model = xgb.train(params3, train_xgb_split, 1000, watch_list, early_stopping_rounds=50,
                              verbose_eval=10)
# xgb_trained_model.save_model("predict/model/xgb_model_all")
print("feature importance 0:")
importance = xgb_trained_model.get_fscore()
temp1 = []
temp2 = []

for k in importance:
    temp1.append(k)
    temp2.append(importance[k])

print("-----")
feature_importance_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'column': temp1,
    'importance': temp2,
}).sort_values(by='importance')

# print(feature_importance_df)

feature_sort_list = feature_importance_df["column"].tolist()
feature_importance_list = feature_importance_df["importance"].tolist()
print()
for i,item in enumerate(feature_sort_list):
    print(item,feature_importance_list[i])


train_x_xgb = xgb.DMatrix(train_x_pd_split)
train_predict = xgb_trained_model.predict(train_x_xgb)

print(train_predict)

train_predict_binary = (train_predict >= 0.5) * 1
print("TRAIN DATA SELF")
from sklearn import metrics
print('LogLoss: %.4f' % metrics.log_loss(train_y_pd_split, train_predict))
print('AUC: %.4f' % metrics.roc_auc_score(train_y_pd_split, train_predict))
print('ACC: %.4f' % metrics.accuracy_score(train_y_pd_split, train_predict_binary))
print('Recall: %.4f' % metrics.recall_score(train_y_pd_split, train_predict_binary))
print('F1-score: %.4f' % metrics.f1_score(train_y_pd_split, train_predict_binary))
print('Precesion: %.4f' % metrics.precision_score(train_y_pd_split, train_predict_binary))

print()
valid_xgb = xgb.DMatrix(valid_x_pd)
valid_predict = xgb_trained_model.predict(valid_xgb)

print(valid_predict)

valid_predict_binary = (valid_predict >= 0.5) * 1
print("TEST DATA PERFORMANCE")
from sklearn import metrics
print('LogLoss: %.4f' % metrics.log_loss(valid_y_pd, valid_predict))
print('AUC: %.4f' % metrics.roc_auc_score(valid_y_pd, valid_predict))
print('ACC: %.4f' % metrics.accuracy_score(valid_y_pd, valid_predict_binary))
print('Recall: %.4f' % metrics.recall_score(valid_y_pd, valid_predict_binary))
print('F1-score: %.4f' % metrics.f1_score(valid_y_pd, valid_predict_binary))
print('Precesion: %.4f' % metrics.precision_score(valid_y_pd, valid_predict_binary))
```

But result shows that xgboost do not fit the data:

```
TRAIN DATA SELF
LogLoss: 0.6931
AUC: 0.5000
ACC: 0.5000
Recall: 1.0000
F1-score: 0.6667
Precesion: 0.5000

TEST DATA PERFORMANCE
LogLoss: 0.6931
AUC: 0.5000
ACC: 0.5000
Recall: 1.0000
F1-score: 0.6667
Precesion: 0.5000
```

Comment: What are these two sentences? Are them just a normal Language sentences in Chinese? If yes how did you encode them then? How large is your dataset? A lot might be going on..

Comment: @MajidMortazavi I have post them all

Comment: Where do you explain what those "我想说" sentences are? Good luck then, I could not follow what your actual problem is.

Comment: The problem is to judge whether the two sentences are the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I obtained 100% converge. Here are differences between the configurations:

1. I set `min_child_weight` to 0. It’s unreasonable to set it to 20 and expect XGBoost to find split.
2. I removed `colsample_bytree`, you only have 1 features, I don’t think sampling is a good choice.